# SCI FI book about single-man teleportation spacecraft found in our solar system?

Tags: story-identification, books, teleportation

All I can remember about the plot is that some space archaeologists/explorers discovered a cave on maybe one of Jupiter's moons and inside were a bunch of single-man spacecraft with one button inside. When someone entered and pressed the button, it would teleport them and the ship away somewhere and I think the ship would automatically return about a minute later.

The first few tests went really well and the test pilots returned excited they'd been to another planet or whatever. But then one ship returned and the pilot was burnt to death (maybe he'd teleported too close to a sun?).

I think the main characters were a man and a woman but I can't remember for sure. This was a paperback I picked up at the library in the late 90s or early 2000s. I thought it was written by Jack McDevitt, but I've been through summaries of all the books I can find by him online and it doesn't seem to be one of his. Similar style of story though.

Comment: Reminiscent a little of *Gateway* by Pohl, could it be that? There are several id questions about that book already.

Comment: I just read the plot summary for that and the premise is pretty similar but it's not quite right. I'm pretty confident the ships (or devices) were teleporting out of the cave, not actually flying out and back from a destination. I don't recognize the general plot either. Thanks anyway though!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Ruling out *Gateway* is good and now I'll try to think of other possibilities.

Comment: I take it back, this was the book! I checked with a family member who also read it back then and the Gateway plot jogged his memory a bit more than it did mine. Thanks so much :)

Comment: OK, cool. So I'll close this as a duplicate since you confirmed the id in a comment. There's nothing bad about having it closed that way, it will help other people find the answer. Welcome to scifi stack exchange!